OpenShift REST API to trigger clusters upgrade in an effort to automate cluster upgrade process
Wondering if anyone has experience in OpenShift cluster upgrade automation?
I'm looking at the automation feasibility to manage OpenShift clusters upgrade through REST API.
My OpenShift clusters run in a disconnected environment.
Currently, once I have completed the necessary preparation tasks for cluster upgrade, I'd execute the following sample command through CLI to trigger the upgrade:
$ oc adm upgrade --allow-explicit-upgrade=true --to-image=<registry_hostname>:<port>/ocp4.12.26/openshift@sha256:xxx --allow-upgrade-with-warnings=true --force=true

Is there a corresponding REST API for this oc command or any other alternatives?
I've looked through the OpenShift REST API docs and couldn't find much information.

The oc command interacts with OpenShift using the API. If you can accomplish something using oc or kubectl, then of course there's an API for it.

To trigger an upgraed, you need to update the ClusterVersion resource. If your cluster has something like this:
$ kubectl get clusterversion version -o yaml
apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
kind: ClusterVersion
metadata:
  name: version
spec:
  channel: stable-4.13
  clusterID: ...
  desiredUpdate:
    version: 4.13.13

Then to upgrade to, say, 4.13.39 you would need to patch the resource to set spec.desiredUpdate.version to 4.13.39. If you wanted to upgrade to 4.14.<whatever> you would need to also update spec.channel to an appropriate channel name.
You can use issue a PATCH request to the appropriate API endpoint to make this change.

The status element of the ClusterVersion resource will contain a list of available upgrades.
Note that you can run kubectl or oc with --v=8 to show all of the API requests the tool is making when executing a command.
